# How to dismiss an android pop up window using an okay button

Tags: java, android, android-popupwindow

I'm making an app for a school project and I'm stuck on one area.
I want to use an okay button to dismiss the pop up window. 
If you have any suggestions or if there is a better way to implement popups please share them.

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class Pop extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popwindow);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.5));

}
}
```

Java code^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="John Baptist de La Salle was a French priest, educational reformer, and founder of the Institute of the Brothers of the Christian Schools. He is a saint of the Roman Catholic Church and the patron saint of teachers."
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/okButton_who"
    android:textColor="#00E676"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

XML^

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you use full activity to show Pop up? You can use Dialog or Popup Window instead, refer to these links http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work, but you can try:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popwindow);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.5));

    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_who);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Or else you could use Dialogs or DialogFragments as akadouri suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) or [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use AlertDialog to do this.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);

    builder.setTitle(title);        // If you want a header title
    builder.setCancelable(false);   // If you want to stop user dismissing with back button
    builder.setMessage(message);    // Message to user

    //If you want custom layout (not needed)
    LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pin_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView)

    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveLable, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Do something
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeLable, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Do something, or remove if you dont want negative button
        }
    });

    builder.show();
```